# pgwModal: using a trigger option duplicates a HTML markup of a content of a modal in a page. How to get rid of duplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pgwmodal

I'm trying to use a [pgwModal](http://pgwjs.com/pgwmodal/) plugin to generate modals. It has an option `target`:

> "target" - The selector (#div or .class) will be used for push its
>   HTML content into the modal.

Example code. Please pay attention to `style="display: none;"`. That is the way they suggest to hide my custom modal content from the page:

```
<div id="modalContent" style="display: none;">
    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">Modal Example 2</strong>
    <button type="button" id="sbmt_btn">Submit</button>
</div>


$.pgwModal({
    target: '#modalContent',
    title: 'Modal title 2',
    maxWidth: 800
});
```

But with this technique I end up with two absolutely same markups on the page - the one is my custom `#modalContent` with `style="display: none;"` and another one is that is pushed inside a generated modal. So I have two buttons with an `id="sbmt_btn"`. And of course `$("#sbmt_btn")` selector doesn't work. I don't think that it is right behavior but they suggest it in their Documentation. What do I do wrong? How to get rid of modal duplication?

The same question on their Github page:
https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwModal/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var html = '<div id="modalContent" style="display: none;"><strong style="color: #ff0000;">Modal Example 2</strong><button type="button" id="sbmt_btn">Submit</button></div>';


$.pgwModal({
    target: '#modalContent',
    title: 'Modal title 2',
    maxWidth: 800,
    content: html
});
```

You can omit the target if you want.