# jQuery binding issue inside pgwModal

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, popup, pgwmodal

I am using a modal popup for Login, I have a username and password field only, and I am using the following code ---

```
 $(document).on("submit", "#testForm", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($('#testForm .requiredxx').length);
             $('.requiredxx').each(function() {
                      var $this = $(this);
                      if($this.val() == ''){
                            console.log('blank');
                        }
                });
           });
```

here is html:

```
<div id="pgContent">
    <form action="#" id="testForm">
    <li><input type="text" class="requiredxx" placeholder="user name"></li>
    <li><input class="requiredxx" type="password" placeholder="password"></li>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

using this code, working, but when I check console, I can see It logs the length is  4, actually I have only 2 elements with '.requiredxx'. When I alert the error message, then also, It alerts 4 times when the fields are blank, I am using the above form inside pgwmodal(http://pgwjs.com/pgwmodal/). the modal code is this,

```
$('.testlink2').on('click', function() {
                $.pgwModal({
                    target: '#pgContent',
                    maxWidth: 350,
                     titleBar: false
                });
        });
```

Any Idea, why this happens??

Oooops!  I found this question in SO, please refer this also, this says real issue is with PGWModal plugin, Link  -
[pgwModal: using a trigger option duplicates a HTML markup of a content of a modal in a page. How to get rid of duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714086/pgwmodal-using-a-trigger-option-duplicates-a-html-markup-of-a-content-of-a-moda)

Comment: if you open your page source and search for `.requiredxx` how many times do you see it?

Comment: can you add the html code of `testForm`?

Comment: I have updated the question with HTML, please check

Comment: Please refer this link -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714086/pgwmodal-using-a-trigger-option-duplicates-a-html-markup-of-a-content-of-a-moda